# IE + Flash + Server Certificate error

Tags: php, flash, internet-explorer, ssl-certificate

```
https://apressadosanonimos.net/list_a.php
```

this works great with all browsers but IE

In IE, I get a certificate error:

```
"The certificate you are viewing does not match the name of the site you are trying to view"
```

And a:

```
"Only secure content will be displayed"
```

error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE and which version of Windows?

Using my psychic debugging skills, I'm going to guess you tested this on Windows XP and the server is using the Server Name Indicator (SNI) TLS extension to negotiate which certificate to send. (There's a good indication that the server is using SNI, since it returns a "unknown hostname" TLS warning, which it shouldn't since that [causes other problems too](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/03/29/https-request-hangs-.net-application-connection-on-tls-server-name-indicator-warning.aspx))

Since XP doesn't support the SNI TLS extension, no version of IE on XP will send the SNI field so the server returns the wrong certificate and IE complains.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/07/certificate-name-mismatch-warnings-and-server-name-indication.aspx for discussion.

Your site works fine in most non-IE browsers on Windows XP, in any browser on Windows Vista and later, and on most mobile browsers.

Comment: tested this on Windows 7 and windows 8. IE from 9 till 11. Some work some dont.I think it depends on ie security settings.

Comment: This site works fine on my Win8.1 machine. Even on Windows 7+, your HTTPS settings need to be correct (e.g. the defaults). Inside IE's Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Security section, you must have TLS1.0 enabled and SSL2.0 disabled. Otherwise, the SNI TLS extension cannot be sent.

Comment: Solved... the problem was with Flash FLV player... that was sending http requests, changed video player and its working fine now! Thank you for helping..